# How to create an Input Button in ASP.NET 1.1

Tags: button, input, asp.net-1.1

I'm trying to create a generic **<input type="button">** button in ASP.Net using an ASP.Net control and I'm unfortunately stuck using ASP.Net 1.1 right now.  I know you can use the UseSubmitBehavior="False" attribute in later versions of ASP.Net but I can't seem to find a way to do this in ASP.Net 1.1.  Is there a way to do this or will I need to just create the HTML version of the control and set it to runat="server"?

Comment: Looks like my original version of the post left out an important element... the <input type="button"> part... I can't seem to find a way to create a button that is not a submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like you just can't do this with an asp.net control.  The only way I was able to make this work was with an `<input type="button" runat="server">` control.

Answer (score 2):

[ASP:Button in ASP.NET 1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm sure my original post looked extremely basic, I edited it to make the main portion show up now.  I'm looking for a way to make an <input type="button"> with an asp:Button control, not a submit button.